# Writing a DRY HTTP request handler in Java using Android's AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm looking for some help with a kind of bug in my code.  I'm writing an HTTP request handler for my Android application from scratch, and it works just fine but I'm having trouble splitting the different parts of the `POST` and `GET`.  They have some identical logic, so I'm trying to keep it down to one `if` clause.  I'm extending `AsyncTask` so I have `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` methods to handle the actual request and then handle the results respectively.  The request I'm testing is a `GET` request.

**Constructor**

```
public <T extends Exhibitable> HTTPRequestHandler(T exhibiter, String verb, String url) throws MalformedURLException {
    this.exhibiter = exhibiter;
    this.verb = verb;
    this.url = url;

    try {
        mUrlConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
        mUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        mUrlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        mUrlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("Debug", "MalformedURLException", e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Debug", "IOException1", e);
    }
}
```

The `exhibitor` is just so that in my `onPostExecute` method, I can call its command and have it show my data in the way I want it to.

**Problem Code**

My `doInBackground` method is where I'm running into my bug.  I want

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String tmp;

    try {
      mUrlConnection.connect();
      this.in = new DataInputStream(mUrlConnection.getInputStream());
      this.out = new DataOutputStream(mUrlConnection.getOutputStream());

      if(verb.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
          out.write(requestParams.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
      }

      while((tmp = in.readLine()) !=null){
          mStringBuffer.append(tmp);
      }

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  return mStringBuffer.toString();
}
```

I get a `JSONException: Expected literal value...` It doesn't actually seem to be fetching the data.  The exception is thrown in the

**onPostExecute**

```
public void onPostExecute(String result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    Log.d("Debug", "Result is: "+result);
    try {
        exhibiter.exhibit(new JSONObject("{'result':"+result+"}"));
    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e("Debug", "JSONException", e);
    }
}
```

What *does* work is the following code.

**Working request**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... uri)
    if(verb.equalsIgnoreCase("GET")){

        try {
            while((tmp = in.readLine()) !=null){
                mStringBuffer.append(tmp);
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Debug", "IOException2", e);
        }
    }else if(verb.equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
        try {
            while((tmp = in.readLine()) !=null){
                mStringBuffer.append(tmp);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Debug", "IOException3", e);
        }

    }else{
        return "No valid request specified.";
    }

    return mStringBuffer.toString();
}
```

This goes and fetches the result I have on my server - it gives me what I want, but it isn't very DRY.  So what gives?  These seem mostly identical to me.  The only thing that is really different is that in the working block, I give the `mStringBuffer.append(tmp);` its own `try catch` block.  I've tried inserting that into the desired code block, but it still doesn't work.  So is there something I'm missing about `AsyncTask`?

Comment: You can look at my example of doing a synchronous HTTP download of UTF-8 text [here](https://github.com/jselbie/wrekonline/blob/master/src/com/selbie/wrek/ContentDownloader.java). Then that method is wrapped within an AsyncTask [here](https://github.com/jselbie/wrekonline/blob/master/src/com/selbie/wrek/ScheduleFetcherTask.java) to form a complete example of how to do an HTTP request in a background task and parse the JSON as well.

Comment: Also, invoking `URL.openconnection` on the main thread while doing the transfer on the background thread seems unusual to me. Consider doing all the network I/O in the `doInBackground` method.

Comment: The docs for `DataInputStream.readline` have this to say: `This method was deprecated in API level 1. This method cannot be trusted to convert bytes to characters correctly. Wrap this stream with a BufferedReader instead.`

Comment: Wow thanks for those examples, really excellent work.  What is the reason not to split the connection open and read parts?  Does it have trouble closing or something this way?  I'll be sure to use a buffered reader then.